How to download a package and it dependencies in rpm packages?
For example, if I try to install gcc, it request several dependencies.
[root@Server ~]# rpm -Uvh gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        binutils >= 2.30-17 is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64
        cpp = 8.5.0-20.0.3.el8 is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64
        glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64
        libgcc >= 8.5.0-20.0.3.el8 is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64
        libgomp = 8.5.0-20.0.3.el8 is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64
        libisl.so.15()(64bit) is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64
        libmpc.so.3()(64bit) is needed by gcc-8.5.0-20.0.3.el8.x86_64

Is there a way to download gcc as rpm file in other machine which has a connection to the internet (repository) with all dependent packages needed?

I'm going to make the assumption that you're on Fedora or some other Red Hat type of OS, since you're asking specifically about RPM packages.
With that assumption, the answer is 'yes', but with some caveats. On the connected machine, you can run dnf install --downloadonly gcc. This will download the gcc package and all of it's dependencies, but because of the --downloadonly option will not install them, it only download them to disk. You can them scp the downloaded packages over to the system not connected to the internet and install them.
First caveat - if your connected system has a different set of installed packages from your disconnected system, you may not download all dependencies that your second system needs. In other words, if gcc depends on package foo and that package is already installed on the connected system, it will not be downloaded. You will then still be missing a dependency on your disconnected system, since package foo isn't installed there.
Second caveat - if the systems are different versions of Fedora (e.g. connected in F38 and disconnected is F37), this solution will not work.

That's oracle linux 8.

Oracle Linux is a cheap knock-off clone of RHEL, which in turn is a derivative of Fedora, so this solution is equally valid for Fedora, RHEL, and OEL.

You don't have to explain that to a person who's been using RedHat products since RedHat 5 (not, not RHEL 5, RedHat 5 from the last century). I just wanted to let you know, instead of playing guesswork. There was no yum or dnf back then.
